# Having trouble getting a Tower of Hanoi game to function correctly in Qualtrics

Tags: html, css, game-development, qualtrics, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to embed HTML/javascript/CSS code into a graphic/text question in Qualtrics to run a Tower of Hanoi game. Here's a link to a CodePen containing a functional example: https://codepen.io/finnhvman/pen/gzmMaa

I'm able to input the HTML and CSS code without any issues and the layout of the game and the buttons are working. The issue I'm having is that the blocks are not moving from one pole to another. The first block will rise when clicked on, but its functionality stops there. I can't identify where my issue lies so any assistance is much appreciated. Please let me know if more details are
required.

The game uses HTML and CSS. Here's my code:

```css
/* Controls/Logic */

label,
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10vmin;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 52.5vmin;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

input:nth-child(6n + 2),
input:checked+input+input+label {
  left: 0;
}

input:nth-child(6n + 3),
input:checked+input+label {
  left: 30vmin;
}

input:nth-child(6n + 4),
input:checked+label {
  left: 60vmin;
}

label,
input:hover,
input[readonly]:focus+input,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input+input {
  pointer-events: initial;
}

input[readonly],
input:nth-child(6n + 2):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 2),
input:nth-child(6n + 3):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 3),
input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#one~input,
#one~label {
  z-index: 6;
}

#two~input,
#two~label {
  z-index: 5;
}

#three~input,
#three~label {
  z-index: 4;
}

#four~input,
#four~label {
  z-index: 3;
}

#five~input,
#five~label {
  z-index: 2;
}

#six~input,
#six~label {
  z-index: 1;
}

input#zero {
  z-index: 7;
}

input#zero:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[readonly]:focus+input:checked~#zero {
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

input[readonly]:focus+input+input:checked~#zero {
  left: 30vmin;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

input[readonly]:focus+input+input+input:checked~#zero {
  left: 60vmin;
  pointer-events: initial;
}


/* Discs */

.discs {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 10vmin auto 0;
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 35vmin;
}

.disc {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  height: 4vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: order 0.3s step-end;
}

input:checked+input+input+label+.disc {
  order: 3;
}

input:checked+input+label+.disc {
  order: 6;
}

input:checked+label+.disc {
  order: 9;
}

input:focus+input:checked+input+input+label+.disc {
  order: 1;
  transition: order 0s;
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

input:focus+input+input:checked+input+label+.disc {
  order: 4;
  transition: order 0s;
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

input:focus+input+input+input:checked+label+.disc {
  order: 7;
  transition: order 0s;
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes float {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-1vmin);
  }
}

input:focus+input:hover+input+input+label+.disc,
input+input:active+input+input+label+.disc {
  order: 1;
}

input:focus+input+input:hover+input+label+.disc,
input+input+input:active+input+label+.disc {
  order: 4;
}

input:focus+input+input+input:hover+label+.disc,
input+input+input+input:active+label+.disc {
  order: 7;
}

.one {
  margin: 0 10vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea668, #ed7e1d, #e67e22);
}

.two {
  margin: 0 8vmin;
  width: 14vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8ac4ea, #0f9fff, #3498db);
}

.three {
  margin: 0 6vmin;
  width: 18vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f0d775, #fc0, #e6bd19);
}

.four {
  margin: 0 4vmin;
  width: 22vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #666, #000, #333);
}

.five {
  margin: 0 2vmin;
  width: 26vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ee2a8, #09f16a, #2ecc71);
}

.six {
  width: 30vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f2a097, #ff3a24, #e74c3c);
}


/* Spacers/Separators */

.spacer {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: flex 0.3s;
}

.separator {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.a {
  order: 2;
}

.ab {
  order: 3;
}

.b {
  order: 5;
}

.bc {
  order: 6;
}

.c {
  order: 8;
}

input[readonly]:focus+input:hover~.a,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input:hover~.b,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input+input:hover~.c {
  transition: flex 0s;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

input[readonly]:focus+input:checked~.a,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input:checked~.b,
input[readonly]:focus+input+input+input:checked~.c {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* Winning */

.win {
  z-index: 7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -10vmin;
  bottom: -7.5vmin;
  color: #966f33;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 6vmin;
  line-height: 17.5vmin;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~input:nth-child(6n + 4):checked~.win {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: initial;
}


/* Everything Else */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5vmin;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5vmin;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(150, 111, 51, 0.4), rgba(150, 111, 51, 0.2)), repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #eec487, #eec487 3vmin, #f3cf9a 3vmin, #f3cf9a 6vmin, #f8d8a2 6vmin, #f8d8a2 9vmin, #f1ca88 9vmin, #f1ca88 12vmin, #f4d09e 12vmin, #f4d09e 15vmin, #faddb0 15vmin, #faddb0 18vmin, #eec88a 18vmin, #eec88a 21vmin);
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

.tower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5vmin;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  width: 5vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d7b889, #b27315, #966f33);
}

.a {
  left: 12.5vmin;
}

.b {
  left: 42.5vmin;
}

.c {
  left: 72.5vmin;
}

.bottom {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  width: 95vmin;
  height: 7.5vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), transparent), linear-gradient(#b27315, #966f33 13%, #faddb0 14.5%, #faddb0 27.5%, #966f33 29%, #966f33 42%, #faddb0 43.5%, #d7b889 56.5%, #966f33 58%, #966f33 71%, #d7b889 72.5%, #d7b889 85.5%, #966f33 87%, #b27315);
}

button {
  margin: 7.5vmin auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  width: 35vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c39550, #966f33);
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #caa163, #a77b39);
}

button:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #cf9844, #9e6f29);
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Tower of Hanoi</h1>
<form>
  <div class="discs">
    <input id="one" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="one" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="one" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="one" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="one"></label>
    <div class="disc one"></div>

    <input id="two" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="two" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="two" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="two" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="two"></label>
    <div class="disc two"></div>

    <input id="three" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="three" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="three" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="three" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="three"></label>
    <div class="disc three"></div>

    <input id="four" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="four" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="four" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="four" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="four"></label>
    <div class="disc four"></div>

    <input id="five" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="five" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="five" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="five" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="five"></label>
    <div class="disc five"></div>

    <input id="six" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>
    <input name="six" type="radio" tabindex="-1" checked>
    <input name="six" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <input name="six" type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="six"></label>
    <div class="disc six"></div>

    <input id="zero" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly>

    <div class="spacer a"></div>
    <div class="separator ab"></div>
    <div class="spacer b"></div>
    <div class="separator bc"></div>
    <div class="spacer c"></div>

    <div class="tower a"></div>
    <div class="tower b"></div>
    <div class="tower c"></div>

    <div class="win">You win! :)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <button type="reset">New Game</button>
</form>
```